# InvalidArgumentError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. ; Unknown error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorboard

i am trying to train keggle cats and dogs image dataset. i needed to see tensorboard outputs. but it came with an error

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import pickle
import time
import datetime

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=f".\\logs\\MODEL\\", histogram_freq=1, write_grads=True)

X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))
y = np.asarray(pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb")))

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.3, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

this is the error message

```
<ipython-input-52-2af34454ac99> in <module>
     33 
     34 model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 35 model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.3, callbacks=[tensorboard])
     36 
     37 

InvalidArgumentError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: .\logs\MODEL\train/events.out.tfevents.1573665973.????.5560.13886.v2 : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
; Unknown error
    Creating writable file .\logs\MODEL\train/events.out.tfevents.1573665973.????.5560.13886.v2
    Could not initialize events writer. [Op:CreateSummaryFileWriter]
```

i am using jupyter notebook, tesorflow version 2

Comment: Are you running the notebook on Windows OS  or mac/linux/unix?  I'm wondering about the direction of the slashes in TensorBoard(log_dir=....).

Comment: on windows I've tried both \ and / nothin's working

Comment: You cannot have question marks in a filename.